# PL/SQL: How to execute an SP which preforms a DML and has a return value?

Tags: oracle, syntax, plsql

I have a stored procedure with the following header:

```
FUNCTION SaveShipment (p_user_id IN INTEGER, p_transaction_id IN INTEGER, p_vehicle_code IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL, p_seals IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL) RETURN INTEGER;
```

And I am having trouble running it from TOAD's Editor.  I cannot run it as part of a select from dual statement because it preforms DML, but if I try the following syntax which I saw recommended on some forum:

```
var c integer;
exec :c := orm_helper.orm_helper.SAVESHIPMENT (9999, 31896, NULL, '');
print c;
```

I get:

```
ORA-01008: not all variables bound
Details:
BEGIN :c := orm_helper.orm_helper.saveshipment (9999, 31896, null, ''); END;
Error at line 2
ORA-01008: not all variables bound
```

What's the proper syntax to run this sp manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you calling the stored procedure from another SP?

I think the syntax is (if I recall correctly):

```
declare
     c integer;
begin

c:=storedProc(...parameters...);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you could probably SELECT  orm_helper.orm_helper.SAVESHIPMENT (9999, 31896, NULL, '') FROM DUAL.